# React Native - How to pass from screen to another screen?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I have an simple application that have just two screens: Login and Home. I want to go to Home screen from Login screen. I don't want to use a Navigator, if it is possible. This is my code:

**Index.js**

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './src/App';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App);
```

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <LoginPage />
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

**LoginPage.js**

```
export class LoginPage extends Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { email: '', password: '' };
    }

    goToHomePage = () => {
        // HERE!!!!!!
    };

    onButtonPress = () => {
        this.goToHomePage();
    };

    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <TextInput
                    style={Styles.textInput}
                    onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({email})}
                    placeholder={'Email'}
                    value={this.state.email}
                />

                <TextInput
                    style={Styles.textInput}
                    onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}
                    secureTextEntry
                    placeholder={'Password'}
                    value={this.state.password}
                />

                <Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('HomePage')}
                    title="Login"
                    color="#841584"
                    accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
                />
            </View>
        );
    };
}
```

**HomePage.js**

```
export class HomePage extends Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    goToLoginPage = () => {
        // HERE !!!!!!
    };

    onButtonPress = () => {
        this.goToLoginPage();
    };

    render () {
        return (
            <View style={Styles.container}>
                <View>
                    <LoginHeader Title={'Titulo do HomePage'} />
                </View>

                <Button
                    style={Styles.button}
                    title={'Logout'}
                    onPress={this.onButtonPress}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

So, how can I implement a method for move to screens with this code? I've tried to use `react-native-navigation` and `react-navigation`, but does not work for me in this case.

**EDIT**

I've tried to use this:

**App.js**

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        HomePage: HomePage,
        LoginPage: LoginPage,
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'LoginPage',
    }
);

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <RootStack />
        );
    }
}
```

export default App;

**LoginPage.js**

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

export class LoginPage extends Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { email: '', password: '' };
    }

    goToHomePage = () => {
        // HERE!!!!!!
    };

    onButtonPress = () => {
        this.goToHomePage();
    };

    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <TextInput
                    style={Styles.textInput}
                    onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({email})}
                    placeholder={'Email'}
                    value={this.state.email}
                />

                <TextInput
                    style={Styles.textInput}
                    onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}
                    secureTextEntry
                    placeholder={'Password'}
                    value={this.state.password}
                />

                <Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('HomePage')}
                    title="Login"
                    color="#841584"
                    accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
                />
            </View>
        );
    };
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "does not work for me in this case"? This is the exact correct usage.

Comment: Just don't work. Show multiple errors.

Comment: What are those errors?

Comment: The main error is that the screen must be a React Component. For example: says the LoginPage must be a React Component.

Comment: Can you also show what you've actually tried? There's no code show that sets up or interacts with either navigation library that you've mentioned. If possible, share the repo and the specific code and errors that you're encountering.

Comment: @KimRuan Which means you did something wrong with the setup. Could you show us what you tried with that (and specify which lib you're using)

Comment: The 'EDIT' Code is what I've tried to do. The HomePage is like LoginPage. The other error that appears is "undefined is not an object(evaluanting '_this3.props.navigation.navigate')

Answer (score 0):

Do you import React, {Component} from "react"?

Comment: In LoginPage.js change export class LoginPage .. to export default class LoginPage  and same for HomePage.js. In App.js import them as: import LoginPage from "./LoginPage" <-path to your files